# Domain-wide installed script not appearing to Domain Admin's marketplace apps gallery whilst being publicy available

Tags: google-apps-script, publish

I'm having trouble making my publicly available app script visible to the Domain Admins for domain-wide installation.

G Suite Marketplace SDK is enabled, with the [Configuration] tab configured.  The [Publish] tab never seems to enable the [Publish] button, with the warning "This form is only for specific add-ons".

My app has recently been reviewed and allowed to proceed by the review team, and I can see in the Chrome Web Store that my app has been published

```
Published Version 14          Published
Draft Version 15 - Public     Pending Review
                              GAM: Published
```

The perma link is available to install the app individually:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/seal-atn/mojoekeedapimnnamfjgmnoihijnming?utm_source=permalink

However it's not available in the G Suite Marketplace.  I can only locate the application when searching for it within a Google Doc.  The application doesn't appear to be visible to the Domain Admin user, so they are unable to push the application down onto their end-users

I've read somewhere that there needs to 2 listings in the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard, one for the G Suite Marketplace and one for the Chrome Web Store.  I've followed the instructions for for publishing domain-wide installation: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-for-domains

I now have two entries in my chrome dashboard, the new entry is in the following state:

- Published
- GAM: Pending

Yet the Domain Admins still cannot see the app, even though it's publicly available.

I'm very confused

My details are:
    "api_console_project_id": "820114923602"
    googleapps_sdk?project=project-id-5892627631604572744

Comment: You may check this [support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172981?hl=en&ref_topic=1056394) where it stated that, *Most apps are available immediately after deployment. In some cases, there may be a delay of up to 24 hours before the application is displayed.*

Comment: You do NOT need 2 listings in your developer dashboard.  GAM is approved separately from the Chrome Web Store, and having the OAuth scopes approved does not guarantee that your add-on will be publicly approved.  There is probably an issue with your settings in the Google Cloud Platform for the "APIs and Services -> Credentials -> OAuth Consent Screen"   If that's not set up correctly, then your GAM listing will be Pending forever, and no one will contact you or tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I got the same advice from the docs addon advisor, to just wait another 24 hours.  Well, another 24 hours has passed and there is no change - as I expected.  There appears to be very little support for publishing in the G Marketplace.  No feedback from the system to say why it's not appear.  What are developers supposed to do?